# Error al ejecutar comando python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Buen día a todos.

Estoy aprendiendo Django con un tutorial de YouTube de Pildoras Informáticas. Funcionaba bien hasta que tocó cambiar el idioma en el archivo settings.py; al intentar pasarlo al español dio un error y no fue posible volver a arrancar el servidor. Intenté regresando el settings.py al idioma original, pero me sigue dando un error que no salía antes al ejecutar el comando python manage.py runserver:

```
PS C:\Users\Andrés\Documents\Proyecto Django\TiendaOnline> python manage.py runserver
Watching for fie changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 197, in connect        
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__       
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 212, in build_graph     
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 76, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 56, in has_table      
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 260, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 236, in _cursor        
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 197, in connect        
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Andrés\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

Este es mi settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for TiendaOnline project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '_lq3q6!a@!)ret-hx%*b1si698=0-!@cxap^f91*t98iml5qw^'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'gestionPedidos',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'TiendaOnline.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'TiendaOnline.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'ArticulosClientes',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'DATABASE_PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Mi versión de django es la 3.0.8
Mi versión de PostgreSQL es la 12
Sistema operativo: Windows 10
Estoy usando Visual Studio Code

Soy nuevo en Django, por lo que acudí a revisar la documentación oficial del sitio, sin embargo no logro comprender cuál es la falla. Por lo que señala, creo que es alguna clase de error de conexión, así que probé a reiniciar el servidor, asegurarme de que los puertos fueran los correctos, cerciorarme de que los nombres de usuario y contraseña no tienen conflictos, pero no logro sortear el error.

Espero que alguien pueda echarme una mano, pues estoy atascado aqui y no puedo avanzar porque el servidor ya no funciona.

Saludos.

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Agradezco a todos, pude encontrar la solución, misma que comparto en caso de que fuera de utilidad en un futuro:

1. Pude determinar que el error especifico debería mostrarse en

> `django.db.utils.OperationalError`

sin embargo, al haber cambiado el idioma desde el archivo settings.py, se modificaron a su vez diversas lineas del documento postgresql.conf (usualmente en C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data), en específico:

> lc_messages = 'en-us'

Al cambiarla al idioma español, quedó así:

> lc_messages = 'Spanish_Mexico.1252'

Sin embargo, el sistema no es capaz de mostrar los códigos de error en español, por eso no fue posible determinar que estaba saliendo mal; una vez modificado el archivo postgresql.conf y regresando esta linea a su valor en inglés original, pude percatarme de que el error derivaba de hacer referencia a la base de datos "ArticulosClientes" cuando el nombre real de esta es "articulosclientes" (todo en minúscula).

El servidor está funcionando nuevamente, por lo que doy por concluido el tema.

Comment: Muy buena la solución que propones, ya haciendo ese cambio ya se pude ver el error a detalle, gracias por regresar a compartir la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

1.checa este [enlace](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/internacionalizacion-en-django/) para lo del cambio y recuerda siempre hacer las respectivas migraciones a veces sucede que olvidas migrate y make migrations
y en data base prueba con esto

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Django apps...
    'psycopg2_extension',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me sirve de orientación para el tema de la internacionalización. Pude solucionar el problema modificando el archivo postgresql.conf de la forma en que señalo en la edición de la pregunta. Te agradezco mucho la ayuda :)

Comment: @andres_rr recuerda aceptar la respuesta si resolvió tu problema, dando click en el check con forma de visto, situado en la parte superior izquierda de la respuesta :)

Comment: @Julio Cesar Sucede que resolví el problema, pero no fue mediante lo propuesto por Pedro Alfonzo. Señalé el método en una edición a mi pregunta principal, en caso de que sea útil para alguien más, pero vamos, la respuesta de Pedro Alfonzo no fue apropiada para resolver mi situación (y de cualquier manera lo agradezco infinitamente).

Comment: @andres_rr No hay problema, por otra parte lo ideal seria que dicha actualización que explica como lo solucionaste la publicaras como respuesta y aceptes esta :)